# NextJS + Custom Backend

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm starting a project and I have to decided the frontend infrastructure and arch.

My backend part is a NestJS + Typescript with a layer arch. Simple but useful with a JWT authentication.

But for the frontend part I'm struggling deciding what to use:

1. NextJS with NextAuth: I've been reading for a while and I'm still not able to figure out if there is a way to connect my backend with the NextAuth part. I guess I will be able. Any pro/cons?
2. Plain React: this is the option that I don't want to use. I think I'd like to have some problems solved from scratch.
3. Any other option?

Thanks!